# Laravel url parameter returning 404 once hosted

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel website. Everything is working fine on localhost. But once hosted online with 1&1, when I add a parameter in the route, it's returning an error 404 (not found).

In 1&1 the root url is redirecting to the file "public" of my laravel project.

And the .htaccess in this public file looks like that :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Does someone know what could be the problem ?

Comment: Check your file permissions

Comment: give permission to storage directory. Also you can refer to this link https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.sx71wplr3

Comment: I set permissions to 777 for the storage folder, but it didn't solve the issue. Do we really need to do all of the stuff described in this link to set a laravel project for production ? I didn't do any of that, I don't even understand it...

Comment: Are you using cPanel?  There is a simple guide to set up Laravel on cPanel. Also should never really use 777 permissions for anything especially storage.

Comment: what is cPanel ? I did it on terminal with ssh

Comment: no one knows ?...

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following artisan commands on your host:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:clear
```

If you don't have access to run these commands, you can call them in code using `Artisan::call('optimize')` etc.

Comment: Both commands returned me this error : 

$ php artisan optimize
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/homepages/27/d591094540/htdocs/fabiencohen/artisan</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/homepages/27/d591094540/htdocs/fabiencohen/artisan</b> on line <b>31</b><br />